# Calling a HTTPS secure REST service using a REST Endpoint in BPM

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I can make HTTP REST call inside a BPM Process. How do I do a secure HTTPS call. In Oracle I have to add the certificate to a wallet and then make the call. So how do you do that in WSO2 as it fails if I change the URL from HTTP to HTTPS ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the certificates to client-truststore as in [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores#CreatingNewKeystores-Step3:Importingcertificatestothetruststore).